# Websocket, Ratchet, Autobahn, can't connect

Tags: websocket

im facing following issue:

1. I open up the WS server on the live-server -> running
2. I open up my project on my localhost -> can connect to WS server
3. I open up my project on the live-server ( www.myproject.com ) -> can't connect to WS server

Any idea? Do i need to open any ports?

Answer (score 0):

Try with wss:// . If there is a proxy in the middle it may be interfering.

Also, have you mapped the TCP port you are using for WebSockets to the server where the app runs? If you ate using a non standar port (like 80 or 443) it may be not mapped.

Comment: well, it works from my local apache server. ws://mywebsite.com:8181 . same command to connect on the live-website. Just not working. And i dont know why.

Comment: That does not matter. You may have a proxy between you and your live-website, a proxy in your ISP network, out of your control.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

adding this to my .htaccess ( in the web folder ) actually solved it. I was adding it cuz of another error..but it solved this problem as well.

```
RewriteBase /
DirectorySlash Off

# remove trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]
```

Strange.